# Error: Object of class App\Http\Resources\ProductAttributeResource could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm using method in my model to mutate a single response to my client

When call product Laravel using this method name by default?

```
/**
 * Returns product attributes data to use in the API response.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection
 */
public function getAttributes()
{
    return ProductAttributeResource::collection($this->attributes);
}
```

Debugger show this area:

> C:\xampp\htdocs.../...\vendor\Laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php:521

```
protected function castAttribute($key, $value)

{
    $castType = $this->getCastType($key);

    if (is_null($value) && in_array($castType, static::$primitiveCastTypes)) {
        return $value;
    }
    switch ($castType) {
        case 'int':
        case 'integer':
            return (int) $value;
        case 'real':
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in my case i use a reserved method name in my model

for example i define a new attribute() method for my one to many relation that i should choose another name for it

just need to rename your getAttributes to getAttribute method in your model

because this name used by Model Class

Comment: i use attribute() method in my model.

just need to rename that method

laravel use attribute() and overwrited.

but i want to connect my model to attribute table.